# How do I filter out duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I have two poorly designed tables Form and FormDetails that I am trying to clean up.

The Form table holds information about the status of a form in my application:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| form_id | status_id   | form_created_by |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1           | abc             |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | def             |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

form_id, in the Form table, is the **primary key**.

The FormDetails table holds additional information about the form:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| form_id | status_id   | process_id      |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 2           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

form_id, in the Form table, is **NOT** primary or foreign key. There are no constraints. This table is poorly designed and over time duplicate data has been added to this table.

I would like to clean this table up by copying the unique data into a new FormDetails table and making form_id a foreign key to the Form table.

In order to achieve this I have tried the following query:

```
select * 
from FormDetails fd
right join Form f on f.form_id = fd.form_id and f.status_id = fd.status_id
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting rows with duplicate form_id since form_id=2 has two rows with a status_id=3.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| form_id | status_id   | process_id      |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

What I am trying to write is a query that says: select all the rows in FormDetails that correspond to the current Form. If there are duplicates, just pick one of them.

Any idea how I could write such a query?

What I would like to see is:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| form_id | status_id   | process_id      |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2       | 3           | 1               |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server 2005. I've now added sql-server as a tag...

Comment: I'm going by memory, but I think SELECT DISTINCT for MSSQL should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some friends, I managed to find an answer to this problem. The closest answer to my question was @Gordon Linoff but it still wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

In order to determine how many rows in the Form table did not have any corresponding record in the FormDetails table we wrote the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Form
LEFT OUTER JOIN FormDetails ON Form.form_id = FormDetails.form_id 
           AND Form.status_id = FormDetails.status_id
WHERE
      FormDetails.form_id IS NULL
```

When I ran this against my tables it returned 38 rows. This number helped us determine if the query we wrote was returning the correct number of rows. @Gordon Linoff's answer was different by 26 rows so I think it was returning more rows than expected but it was closer than all the other answers and a step in the right direction.

We then put together this query which uses `CROSS APPLY` (a bit of sql which I had never seen before).

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT ad.*
FROM Form f
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FormDetails fd WHERE 
             f.form_id = fd.form_id AND f.status_id = fd.status_id) AS ad
```

When I compare the number of rows that are in the Form table with the number of rows returned by this query I get a difference of 38. This seems to indicate that this is a good solution to my problem.

I wouldn't have ever thought to use CROSS APPLY in order to solve this...but I thought I would document the solution here just in case it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI SQL function `row_number()` to enumerate the rows in `FormDetails` for each `form_id`.  You don't care what the particular order is, so the following should do what you want:

```
select form_id, status_id, process_id
from (select fd.*, row_number() over (partition by form_id order by form_id) as seqnum
      from formdetails fd
     ) fd
where exists (select 1 from forms f where fd.form_id = f.form_id) and
      seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction but something is not quite right. When I `select count(*) from forms` I get 21607. When I count the number of rows returned by your query I get 21581. This lets me know that there are 26 forms that are not being selected by your query.

Comment: I think the problem with this query is that it doesn't give a sequence of 1 to the form detail that has a status that matches the one in the form table. Any idea how to adapt your query to allow for that?

Comment: @mezoid . . . Your question starts "select all the rows in FormDetails ".  There would appear to be 26 forms in `Forms` that are not in `FormDetails`.  If you want these, just remove the `exists` clause.

Comment: I managed to sort the issue out. Your answer definitely pointed me in the right direction. I've posted my own answer with the solution that I used in the end. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM FormDetails fd
RIGHT JOIN Form f ON f.form_id = fd.form_id AND f.status_id = fd.status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `Distinct rows` in `Form` table then Use `Right Outer join` with `Formdetails` table

```
SELECT f.form_id,
       f.status_id,
       f.process_id,
FROM   FormDetails fd
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT form_id,
                                   status_id,
                                   process_id,
                   FROM   Form) f
               ON f.form_id = fd.form_id
                  AND f.status_id = fd.status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do to solve your problem

1- Create a new field that would act as your unique key in the formDetails table.

```
Alter Table formDetails Add formDetail_id int Not Null Identity(1,1) Constraint PKFormDetail Primary Key
```

2- Then I would create a temporary field that would serve for record evaluation of the existing data. I mean the temporary field created (I'll name it Eval) could contain a calculated value from your 3 fields (form_id, status_id and process_id).

```
Alter Table formDetails Add Eval int

Update formDetails Set Eval = form_id * 100000 + status_id * 1000 + process_id
```

Whatever the solution you take, you must take care that the result would not contains "collisions" (depending on the data contained in your table. I mean in that case process_id must be under 1000 and status_id * 1000 must be under 100000).

3- Delete the unwanted rows like this:

```
  Delete x
  FROM ( select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by Eval order by formDetail_id) 
         from [dbo].[formDetails]) x
  Where rn > 1;
```

(You could test it doing a select instead of a delete to be sure of the result before performing the delete operation).

4- Remove the temporary field from you table.

```
Alter Table formDetails Drop Column Eval
```

5- You can now set directly your foreign key between the form_id field of the two tables.

```
Alter Table formDetails Add Constraint FKFormId Foreign Key (form_id) references forms(form_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Form
(
formId INT,
StatusID INT,
FormCreate VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO #Form VALUES(1,1,'abc')
INSERT INTO #Form VALUES(2,3,'def')

CREATE TABLE #Form1
(
formId INT,
StatusID INT,
ProcessID INT
)

INSERT INTO #Form1 VALUES(1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #Form1 VALUES(2,2,1)
INSERT INTO #Form1 VALUES(2,3,1)
INSERT INTO #Form1 VALUES(2,3,1)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Form fd
LEFT JOIN #Form1 f ON f.formId = fd.formId AND f.StatusID = fd.StatusID
```

Comment: Your solution works fine but do not alter the formDetails table.

But from there, it would be possible to recreate completely the formDetail table. So it could work too.